# How to solve this coordinates equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be a $2$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and
\begin{align}
f:\ \mathbb R\times E&\longrightarrow \mathbb R^3
\\ (s,x)&\longmapsto f(s,x)=\big(f_0,f_1,f_2\big)(s,x)
\end{align}
be a bijective linear map. Assume that $\,I\subseteq\mathbb R\,$ and
\begin{align}
\alpha:\ I&\longrightarrow E
\\ s&\longmapsto\alpha(s)
\end{align}
satisfies
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(s,\alpha(s))
\\ f_2(s,\alpha(s))
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
sv_1+u_1
\\ sv_2+u_2
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \forall s\in I.\tag1
\end{align}
for some fixed $(v_1,v_2),(u_1,u_2)\in\mathbb R^2$.

> Then is it true if $\,\alpha(s)=sa+b\,$ for some $\,a,b\in E$ ?

When we consider the case $E=\mathbb R^2$, the question is quite easy to answer. But I wonder if this is true for any other 3 dimensional $E$.

My solution :

Let $\,\mathcal B=\big(e_1,e_2,e_3\big)\,$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R\times E$. The representation matrix of $f$ with respect to these basis is $I_3$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
f_0(s,\alpha(s))
\\ f_1(s,\alpha(s))
\\ f_2(s,\alpha(s))
\end{bmatrix}_{\mathcal B}
=\begin{bmatrix}
s\\ \alpha(s)
\end{bmatrix}_{f^{-1}(\mathcal B)}.\tag2
\end{align}
From (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
f_0(s,\alpha(s))
\\ sv_1+u_1
\\ sv_2+u_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ \alpha(s)
\end{bmatrix}_{f^{-1}(\mathcal B)}+\begin{bmatrix}
s\\ 0_E
\end{bmatrix}_{f^{-1}(\mathcal B)}.
\end{align}
How can I solve this equation ? I hope someone would give me a help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that $f$ is a linear map, its coordinate maps $f_0$, $f_1$ and$f_2$ are also linear maps. That means there exist $a_{10}$, $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{20}$, $a_{21}$, $a_{22}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
f_1(s,x_1,x_2)&=&a_{10}s+a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2,\\
f_2(s,x_1,x_2)&=&a_{20}s+a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2,
\end{eqnarray}
Now you have some function $\alpha:\ I\ \longrightarrow\ E$ on some subset $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ that satisfies
\begin{eqnarray}
u_1+v_1s
&=&f_1(s,\alpha_1(s),\alpha_2(s))
&=&a_{10}s+a_{11}\alpha_1(s)+a_{12}\alpha_2(s),\\
u_2+v_2s
&=&f_2(s,\alpha_1(s),\alpha_2(s))
&=&a_{20}s+a_{21}\alpha_1(s)+a_{22}\alpha_2(s),
\end{eqnarray}
for all $s\in I$, where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2:\ I\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}$ are such that $\alpha(s)=\alpha_1(s)e_1+\alpha_2(s)e_2$ for your favorite basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of $E$. Then
$$s\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{10}\\ a_{20}\end{pmatrix}s
+\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}\\ a_{12}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1(s)\\ \alpha_2(s)\end{pmatrix},$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}v_1-a_{10}\\ v_2-a_{20}\end{pmatrix}s=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}\\ a_{12}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1(s)\\ \alpha_2(s)\end{pmatrix}.\tag{1}$$
This shows that if the square matrix $A:=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}\\ a_{12}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible then
$$\alpha(s)=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1(s)\\ \alpha_2(s)\end{pmatrix}=A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}+A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}v_1-a_{10}\\ v_2-a_{20}\end{pmatrix}s,$$
and so $\alpha(s)$ is linear.

However, if the matrix $A$ is not invertible then this is not necessarily true: Consider the bijective linear map
$$f:\ \Bbb{R}\times E\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^3:\ \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}\ \longmapsto\ \begin{pmatrix}x+y+z\\ x+y\\ x\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then as before we find that
$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1-1\\ u_2-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\end{pmatrix}s=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1(s)\\ \alpha_2(s)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1(s)\\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This tells us nothing about $\alpha_2(s)$, and indeed for the map
$$\alpha:\ I\ \longrightarrow\ E:\ s\ \longmapsto\ (s,s^2),$$
which is clearly not linear whenever $I$ is nontrivial, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}f_1(s,\alpha(s))\\ f_2(s,\alpha(s))\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}s$$

Comment: You were considering $E=\mathbb R^2$.  What about the other case where $E$ is not $\mathbb R^2$ ? We know that since $E$ is a 2 dimensional vectorspace over $\mathbb R$ hence $E$ is linear isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, but it needs not to be $\mathbb R^2$ right ?

Comment: The entire argument carries over to $E$ by choosing an isomorphism with $\Bbb{R}^2$, i.e. by choosing a basis. I have made this more explicit in my answer now.

Comment: I have another similar question. Let $f=(f_1,f_2):\ \mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ be a map satisfies $\forall x=(x_1,x_2),\, y=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb R^2,$
\begin{align}
f_1(x)f_1(y)- f_2(x)f_2(y) \,=\,x_1y_1 - x_2y_2.
\end{align}
Then does $f$ take any point of linear form $sa+b$ to a point of linear form $f(sa+b)=sp+q,\ \forall\,s\in\mathbb R $ ?

Comment: Let $x_1y_1-x_2y_2=\langle x,y\rangle$. I have tried and show that
\begin{align}
\big< sf(a)+f(b) -f(sa+b) ,  sf(a)+f(b) -f(sa+b) \big>\,=\,0,\ \forall s\in\mathbb R.
\end{align}
But this is not an inner product, so it doesn't implies $  sf(a)+f(b) -f(sa+b)=0$.

Comment: @PermQi Consider asking a new question if you have a new question. Also consider accepting this answer if this answers your question.